# Retrieve transaction ID via rest API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

My application uses PayPal java library to make payments. Everything works fine but I can't understand one thing. What exactly is transaction code? Let's say I make a payment and then approve it. As a result I receive the JSON object which has an ID (PAY-***) and transactions->related resources->sale->ID. Both of them I store in the DB in order to show later to user (in case he wants to refund the money). But if I see these payments from PayPal customer portal, in the descriptions of payment I see non of these ID's.. Transaction code is totally different! So which one of them should I store?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal generally uses a transaction ID. It's a 16 character alphanumeric string. This will appear in both your API response and the PayPal site. Assuming REST is like Classic, the Transaction ID is how you will reference the payment for any future operations (capture, refund, etc).

Please note that if you're using Express Checkout (where the customer pays via PayPal account) they will have their own transaction ID for the exact same transaction.

Comment: In my REST response I dont' find it. I'm using the Pay-Chained api

Comment: Even using the standard Pay api I don't get it

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini I'm not a fan of REST because it sometimes overcomplicates things. The transaction ID in a sale request is under the [sale object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#sale-object) (is just called `id`)

Comment: @Machavity but how do you receive a sale object (via RestAPI) after a Express Checkout? The response only conains a PAY-XXXX id.

Comment: @silly When you [capture the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment) it will be under `transactions > related_resources > sale > id`

Comment: @Machavity transactions is a list. So is related resources. Should we just assume that we need the first element in both lists (ie. `.get(0)`)? Or is there a safer way to specify that we want the "sale" `related_resource`?

Comment: @theyuv Might be better as a separate question

Comment: @Machavity Thanks. I have created a question addressing the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606395/how-to-get-sale-id-of-executed-paypal-payment-via-rest-sdk

Comment: @Machavity Hey, if you can take a look at the [question I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606395/how-to-get-sale-id-of-executed-paypal-payment-via-rest-sdk) regarding my comment here I would appreciate it. Thanks.