# How to get Sale Id of executed PayPal payment via REST SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal's REST SDK for java:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK

After executing a payment via the SDK, if someone should choose to refund a payment, I wish to execute the refund via the SDK.

First, I get the details of the payment using the `Payment.get(APIContext, PaymentId)` method.

Then, to execute the refund I need the Sale Id. So I retrieve this from the `Payment` Object retrieved in the previous step with the following call:

`String saleId = ppPayment.getTransactions().get(0).getRelatedResources().get(0).getSale().getId();`

The call above assumes that there is one `Transaction` Object in the list and one `RelatedResources` Object in the `Payment` and `Transaction` Objects, respectively.

My question is: Is it safe to assume that the relevant Transaction and Related Resource Object will always be the first elements in the list?

For the case of the `Transaction` Object I know that there is only one because I am the one creating the payment. For the case of the `RelatedResource` Object I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know which element in the list is relevant to me.

For both lists, is there a way to ensure that the element in the list is the one that is relevant to you? In what case is there more than one `RelatedResource` element in the returned list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
String saleId = "";
         try{
             Payment payment = Payment.get(apiContext, paymentId);
             List<Transaction> transactions = payment.getTransactions();

             for(Transaction transaction : transactions){
                 List<RelatedResources> resources = transaction.getRelatedResources();

                 for(RelatedResources resource : resources){
                     Sale sale = resource.getSale();
                     if(sale != null){
                         saleId = sale.getId();
                         break;
                     }

                 }
             }

             System.out.println(saleId);

         }catch(PayPalRESTException e){
             System.err.println(e.getDetails());
         }
```

I am not sure about Transaction Object, but RelatedResources Object will have more than one element in the returned list if your completed Payment(i.e. sale) is already refunded. In this case, RelatedResources in Transaction of your Payment Object will have multiple elements, one of which would be sale and other would be refund.